# how you can initialize an object in jquery...and then check how to push some values into it?

Tags: jquery

how you can initialize an object in jquery...and then check how to push some values into it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery.

Create an object:

```
let person = { name: "John" }
```

Access properties:

```
person.name // John
```

Update properties:

```
person.name = "George"
```

Comment: can we use it in jquery method

Comment: Yes, you can use JavaScript objects as shown in my example in any jQuery method.